# Captcha not working in PHP/Apache Server

Tags: php, apache, captcha

I created a small code for captcha. I am running PHP on apache2. When I test it, there is no image loaded on the page, and it appears blank. I also check for GD, and it is installed already.

Here is the PHP Code:

```
<?php

$img = imagecreatetrucolor(80,30);

$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
$red = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0);
$pink = imagecolorallocate($img, 2250, 0, 150);

imagefill($img, 0, 0, $black);

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);

?>
```

Any suggestions would be of great help!!

Comment: check the 'error message'

Comment: have a look for this:- http://99webtools.com/blog/php-simple-captcha-script/